# How to let the user select an item from JOptionPane with a double-click

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

In my Java Swing application, I show a list of options to users using a JOptionPane with a JList, using the code below:

```
List<Object> options = getOptions();
JList list = new JList(options.toArray());
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(scrollpane);
scrollpane.getViewport().add(list);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollpane, 
      "Please select an object", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

**How can I let the user select an option by double-clicking it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JList` doesn't provide any special handling of double or triple (or N) mouse clicks, but it's easy to add a `MouseListener` if you wish to take action on these events. Use the [`locationToIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#locationToIndex%28java.awt.Point%29) method to determine what cell was clicked. For example:

```
 list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
             int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
             System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);
          }
     }
 });
```

> I just need to know how to close the dialog after the user
>   double-clicks the item

In this mouse event, you can make use of [`SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent%28java.awt.Component%29) to get the window and dispose it using `window.dispose()` function.

Comment: Almost there! Now, to completely solve my problem, I just need to know how to close the dialog after the user double-clicks the item (from within mouseClicked event, I suppose). But how?

Comment: +1, answers the OP's question, but the user should be able to use the mouse or the keyboard.

Comment: @camickr, i have just checked your added link. quite a nice work. I will look into the source of `ListAction` class. +1 to you for now :)

Comment: @Ricardo, you can look into the camickr's linked class too. It will be useful to you in future when you will like to work with KeyBoard too :)

Answer (score 3):

See [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) for a solution that will allow you to select an Item from the list with the mouse or the keyboard.

In the Action that you create you can use:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```

to get the window that you need to dispose();